# Techniques for not allowing a vb.net program to enter "Not responding mode"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a program that runs a pretty long operation in the background once a user clicks the button. I have implemented a progress bar but if the window is touched or moved then it grays out and says (Not repsonding). Everything still works and when the operation finishes the program resumes function. (But a user would not know this :(

Any ideas on the best way to keep this from happeneing
I working with vb.net in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Been looking into both answers mentioned below, but have yet to play around with them. Is there anything that would possible just stop it from say "timing out"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving your processing out of the main UI thread into a background worker thread is the best solution, but a short term fix just to get the window responding might be to use [Application.DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) in an appropriate place in your processing code.

But be warned that it can create some [re-entrancy problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html) if the user can still perform actions on your form.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that some use of threading would help that. You would send the actual operation into a new thread, different than the thread responsible for the running application.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or the Thread Pool to run tasks on a different thread whilst keeping your UI (user interface) responsive.

Also, check out this excellent free eBook (in C# I'm afraid) for everything you'll need to know about threading:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Introduction